# Ubuntu USB visible but cant select it

Tags: live-usb, usb-drive, usb-installation

I flashed an USB with Ubuntu 22.10, and as I did many times, wanted to change operating system (from Zorin OS to Ubuntu 22.10)

Usually I click here and it enter into the try/install part of the process, but if I select it and press enter, it just get back to this view (I attach image, Kingston is the USB) wont proceed in any way.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygQD3.jpg)

any idea on how to solve it? thanks in advance :)

Comment: How did you create the boot media?

Comment: There probably is a problem with how you flashed the operating system to the USB. Please add more info about the steps you followed as @vidarlo asked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)